# Object #<Text> has no method 'getBoundingClientRect' on XAJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, error-handling

recently, I'm getting very strange error using the libraries XAJAX. Everything seems to work correctly, but Chrome console gives me an error every time I run any element.

The page where I is happening is this:
http://es.woow360.com/

For example clicking on any tab business that appears in the search box it does is load a new panoramic generates this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Text> has no method 'getBoundingClientRect'
WombatUtils.getElementRect
M
U
Y
CrossbrowserMutationObserver.n
d.callbackWrapper
xajax.dom.assign xajax_core.js:210
(anonymous function) xajax_core.js:318
xajax.command.handler.call xajax_core.js:315
xajax.executeCommand xajax_core.js:404
xajax.tools.queue.process xajax_core.js:150
xajax.responseProcessor.xml xajax_core.js:165
xajax.responseReceived xajax_core.js:399
oRequest.request.onreadystatechange xajax_core.js:356
```

Here you have the link to the file where error occurs:
http://es.woow360.com/xajax/xajax_js/xajax_core.js

It's very strange. Until recently it worked fine.
But now fails.

It fails only on this page, also I have other pages that use the same library, and gives the same error.
Even in other domains, where I have loaded the library XAJAX gives the same error.

Not to be that.

The strange thing is that except for the error message, everything works fine.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm trying it out in Firefox 21.0 and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Google Chrome Versión 27.0.1453.93

Comment: Here you have a screenshot:
http://www.pentaxeros.com/images/varios/1369937318Capturadepantalla20130530alas20.png

Comment: Hello, I tried to download the library XAJAX again, and I have installed on my server to see if also gives errror, and continues to fail.

Here is the library in case anyone wants to try:
http://www.xajax-project.org/media//xajax/0.5_final/xajax_0.5_standard.zip

And here it is installed on my server and this is one of the examples that also gives the same error:
http://es.woow360.com/xajax3/examples/thewall/thewall.php

Here you have a screenshot
http://www.pentaxeros.com/images/varios/1369945653Capturadepantalla20130530alas22.png

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same errors/warnings. Add-less chrome extension was the issue. Try to review extensions of your chrome.